# I can't show time and date of the bot message. (react-chatbot-kit)

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a chatbot in react and I want to display the date and time at the top of the chatbot.  I am using react-chatbot-kit library.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26oaU.png)

ActionProvider.jsx

```
  const handleOverview = (options) => {
    // hora y fecha 
    // const prefixedMessage = `${formattedDate} ${formattedTime}`;
     const prefixedMessage = `24/02/2024`;
    const botMessage = createChatBotMessage(
      `Hola!  Soy ${botName}, su asistente virtual. ¿En qué puedo ayudarte hoy?`,
      {
        widget: "preguntasfrecuentes",
        loading: true,
        terminateLoading: true,
        timestamp: prefixedMessage,
        ...options
      }
    );
    setState((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      messages: [...prev.messages, botMessage],
    }));
  };
```

CustomBotMessage.js

```
import React from 'react';

const CustomBotMessage = ({ message, timestamp }) => {
  return (
    <div className="bot-message-container">
      <span className="bot-name">Tec</span>
      <span className="message-date">{timestamp}</span>
      <div className="react-chatbot-kit-chat-bot-message" style={{ marginLeft: '5px', marginTop: '2px' }}>
        <span>{message}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default CustomBotMessage;
```